# MySQL subquery on each record in group by

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

This is the more advanced sequel to an earlier question.

[Here's a link to an SQLFiddle to make things a bit clearer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db932)

I need to return something like (for each location):

> Ground Floor
>   `---------------`
>   Garage
>   - Radiator
>   Kitchen
>   - Cooker
>   - Fridge

There's going to be even more levels than this but if I can get started I should hopefully be able to go further as needed.

Thanks

Comment: Just order your results by location then sublocation, and structure the output as desired in your application code (detecting a change in location/sublocation by comparison with the previous record).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SQL cannot return nested records as you have formatted above, you need only to return a query which orders your rows by floor then by sub_location.  You'll get both the `location` and `sub_location` repeated for each row, but in your application code loop when printing the results, you format them as you have above.

```
SELECT
  location.location_name,
  sublocation.sub_location_name,
  asset.asset_name
FROM
  location
  LEFT JOIN sub_location ON location.location_key = sublocation.location_key
  LEFT JOIN assets ON sub_location.sub_location_key = assets.sub_location_key
ORDER BY
  location.location_name,
  sub_location.sub_location_name
```

When looping over your rowset in your application, you then only print the new location or sub_location when it changes. Formatting is done in code.

Assuming your rows are all in the array `$rowset`:

```
// Store location, sub_location for each loop
$current_loc = "";
$current_subloca = "";
foreach ($rowset as $row) {
  // If the location changed, print it
  if ($row['location'] != $current_loc) {
    echo $row['location_name'] . "\n";
    // Store the new one
    $current_loc = $row['location_name'];
  }
  // If the sub_location changed, print it
  if ($row['sub_location'] != $current_subloc) {
    echo $row['sub_location_name'] . "\n";
    $current_subloc = $row['sub_location_name'];
  }
  echo $row['asset_name'] . "\n";      
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, looks like this will be a lot simpler than I first thought. How do I loop my code so I only get the location and sub_location when it changes?

Comment: Thanks Michael! This is going to do the job nicely. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can display a known-depth hierarchical structure with this solution:

```
SELECT a.name
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CONCAT('- - - - - - - - - -> ', a.asset_name) AS name,
        CONCAT(c.location_key, c.location_name, b.sub_location_name, a.asset_name) AS orderfactor
    FROM asset a
    INNER JOIN sub_location b ON a.sub_location_key = b.sub_location_key
    INNER JOIN location c ON b.location_key = c.location_key

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        CONCAT('- - - - -> ', a.sub_location_name),
        CONCAT(b.location_key, b.location_name, a.sub_location_name)
    FROM sub_location a
    INNER JOIN location b ON a.location_key = b.location_key

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        location_name,
        CONCAT(location_key, location_name)
    FROM location
) a
ORDER BY a.orderfactor
```

For more levels, you could add in more unions to the subselect.

---

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db932/14/0)

---

Example result-set:

```
Ground Floor
-----> Garage
----------> Radiator
-----> Kitchen
----------> Cooker
----------> Fridge
First Floor
-----> Bedroom
----------> Radiator
----------> Taps
Second Floor
-----> Bathroom
----------> Shower
----------> Taps
----------> Toilet
Third Floor
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is in MySQL5

```
SELECT L.location_name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT S.sub_location_name), GROUP_CONCAT(A.asset_name) 
FROM location L
INNER JOIN sub_location S ON L.location_key = S.location_key
INNER JOIN asset A ON A.sub_location_key = S.sub_location_key
GROUP BY S.sub_location_name ORDER BY L.location_key
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db932/9